# About showing datas through subquery

Tags: mysql, terminal, subquery

I have a schema like this

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/690e8

1. how do I show doctorid, doctorname, doctorphone and doctorbirthyear(from the year of doctorbirthdate) where the doctor never done an inspection.
2. how to show medicinename, medicinetypename, and medicineprice where the medicine sold on the 12th month of the year.
3. how do I show medicineid , medicinename, and medicineprice (with USD) where the medicine isnt sold by doctorid = 'dc001'.
4. how to show patientid, patientname, and patientbirthyear (from the year of patientbirthdate) where the patient served by doctor younger than the patient.

My uncle asked me to solve this even though I'm a digital art student (it's complicated), I honestly have almost no idea about mysql, only basic things. Please, I implore you to help me solving these questions. I'll be really grateful!

Comment: share some code/query efforts you took to solve the above,it's not just about posting question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- how do I show doctorid, doctorname, doctorphone and doctorbirthyear(from the year of doctorbirthdate) where the doctor never done an inspection.

```
select doctorid, doctorname, doctorphone , year(DoctorBirthDate) as doctorbirthyear
from msdoctor 
where doctorid not in (select doctorid from transactionheader) ;
```

2- how to show medicinename, medicinetypename, and medicineprice where the medicine sold on the 12th month of the year.

```
select medicinename, medicinetypename,  medicineprice 
from MsMedicineType mt, MsMedicine m , TransactionDetail td, TransactionHeader th
where mt.MedicineTypeID=m.MedicineTypeID and m.MedicineID=td.MedicineID and td.TransactionID=th.TransactionID and month(th.TransactionDate) = 12;
```

3- how do I show medicineid , medicinename, and medicineprice (with USD) where the medicine isnt sold by doctorid = 'dc001'.

```
select medicinename, medicinetypename,  concat(medicineprice,'$') as medicineprice 
from MsMedicineType mt, MsMedicine m , TransactionDetail td, TransactionHeader th
where mt.MedicineTypeID=m.MedicineTypeID and m.MedicineID=td.MedicineID and td.TransactionID=th.TransactionID and th.DoctorID!='dc001';
```

4- how to show patientid, patientname, and patientbirthyear (from the year of patientbirthdate) where the patient served by doctor younger than the patient.

```
select p.patientid, p.patientname, year(PatientBirthDate) as patientbirthyear 
from TransactionHeader th , msdoctor m,  mspatient p 
where th.DoctorID=m.DoctorID and th.PatientID=p.PatientID and PatientBirthDate>DoctorBirthDate;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1st question

```
SELECT DoctorID, DoctorName, DoctorPhone, YEAR(DoctorBirthDate) as 'DoctorBirthYear' 
FROM MsDoctor
WHERE DoctorID NOT IN (SELECT DoctorID FROM TransactionHeader);
```

2nd question

```
SELECT MsMedicine.MedicineName, CONCAT(MsMedicine.MedicinePrice,' USD'), MsMedicineType.MedicineTypeName  
FROM MsMedicine
INNER JOIN MsMedicineType ON MsMedicineType.MedicineTypeID = MsMedicine.MedicineTypeID
WHERE MedicineID IN (
    SELECT MedicineID FROM TransactionDetail
    WHERE TransactionID IN (
       SELECT TransactionID from TransactionHeader
        WHERE MONTH(TransactionDate) = 12
    )
)
```